# Sharing sessions between DNN and Custom app

Tags: asp.net, .net, dotnetnuke, session-state, dotnetnuke-7

I have setup a DNN website with domain

### www.abc.com

Now I require to build a custom application in asp.net and host it in 
domain

### www.custom.abc.com

The users who have logged into DNN (www.abc.com) should not be prompted to login again in www.custom.abc.com.

Basically, I want to share the Sessions used by DNN to my custom application. Is this possible ? Need some ideas for my starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to share authentication cookie, you can do so by setting same keys in the web config.

Please check [Forms Authentication Across Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx)

Sharing sessions is a bit more difficult if those are two different applications, and it would require some custom coding.

Maybe you can add some logic in global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` event to check if user authentication cookie exists (`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`), and if user is authenticated, but session is NULL, just recreate needed session.